# IntellJj Plugin Development - source code of selected java file

Tags: intellij-plugin

I just started my adventure in IntelliJ plugin development.
What I need to do is to generate some code depending on the code of the selected java file. 
I already have setup the environemt and I can succefully run my plugin and I can show my action only on the context menu of java files: what I don't have idea on how to do is how reading the code of the selected file, where for "reading" I mean determining field, method etc..
I can use very well reflection api, but how can I load the class once selected?

This is the current code for showing the menu entry only for java files

```
public class MyConditionalAction extends AnAction {
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        DataContext dataContext = e.getDataContext();
        VirtualFile virtualFile = PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE.getData(dataContext);
        Project project = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT);
        //show popup with file path
        Messages.showMessageDialog(project, virtualFile.getPath(), "Information", Messages.getInformationIcon());
    }

    @Override
    public void update(AnActionEvent e) {
        super.update(e);
        determineVisibility(e);

    }

    private void determineVisibility(AnActionEvent e) {
        DataContext dataContext = e.getDataContext();
        VirtualFile virtualFile = PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE.getData(dataContext);
        e.getPresentation().setVisible(isJava(virtualFile));
    }

    private boolean isJava(VirtualFile file) {
        if (file == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return JavaFileType.INSTANCE.equals(file.getFileType());
    }
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use reflection because the classes being edited are not compiled and not loaded into the IntelliJ IDEA JVM. Instead, you need to use the PSI API.

```
PsiFile psiFile = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
if (psiFile instanceof PsiJavaFile) {
    PsiClass[] classes = ((PsiJavaFile) psiFile).getClasses();
    // and so on
}
```